# Filename being shortened by script

Tags: php, sql-server

I have some php code that connects to a MSSQL, looks up some values and retrieves a file that is stored in binary format. The table has the filename, header and the binary data. Presently my code is downloading the file as expected however, if there is a space in the filename, the name is cut short, as if the space is acting as a delimeter. e.g. value in db "This is an example file.pdf" outputted filename "This" and the browser recognises the pdf type.

My somewhat functional code is below:

```
/* Retrieve and display the data.  
        The return data is retrieved as a binary stream. */  
        if ( sqlsrv_fetch( $stmt ) )  
        {  
            $noticeID = sqlsrv_get_field( $stmt, 0, SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_INT);
            $filename = sqlsrv_get_field( $stmt, 1, SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STRING("UTF-8"));
            $header = sqlsrv_get_field( $stmt, 2, SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STRING(SQLSRV_ENC_BINARY));
            $download = sqlsrv_get_field( $stmt, 3, SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STREAM(SQLSRV_ENC_BINARY));  
            header('Content-Type: '.$header);  
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
            echo "Your file, $filename is ready for download";
            fpassthru($download);  
        }  
        else  
        {  
             echo "Error in retrieving data.</br>";  
             print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true);  
        }
```

I suspect that the issue is that the filename is stored as a VARCHAR(255) in the DB and somehow is breaking the "Content-Disposition" header line. Research brought me to this page but it isn't very clear on how to handle VARCHAR and when I try and "hack" it by guessing (see below) and get a filename "index.php" (although it does download the file)

```
$filename = sqlsrv_get_field( $stmt, 1, SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_VARCHAR);
```

I've also tried this in place of the faulty header line:

```
$filename = sqlsrv_get_field( $stmt, 1, SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STREAM(SQLSRV_ENC_BINARY)))
```

It still cuts off the filename. If there is no space in the filename, the code executes perfectly.

BONUS: does anyone know how I could save the file to the filesystem rather than having a download dialog? This code is proof of concept for a data migration script I'm writing and that would also be very helpful :)

Comment: I am not that familiar with PHP, but I faced similar problems with perl and other languages. Ist it possible, that you have to surround $filename with quotation marks (or the corresponding alternative in PHP...)? Somewhat like you have to do with Window path and file names when creating shortcuts? Might look something like this: header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='$filename'");

Comment: Thanks for the response, tried it and now I get 
**'This**
it added the single quote to the beginning of the filename!

Comment: As I mentioned: I am not so familiar with PHP. What I was trying to achieve was that the header looks something like this: Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="$filename"   or  Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='$filename', where $filename has to be replaced by your string. e.g. Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="This is an example file.pdf"

Comment: @Tyron78 I see what you mean, I've made some progress following your logic & it is a windows issue I think, if I use a function to strip the spaces from the filename and replace with underscores, it appears in full. Very weird, I hope someone has a solution although this will work for now

Comment: Could you please give this a try? As far as I found on the web, this is how strings are concatenated in PHP...: header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'."$filename".'"');

Comment: Hat's off to you! I had originally used the concatenating feature but hadn't included the double quotes! **now all I need to do is figure out how to save the file to the filesystem rather than through a dialog**

Comment: Then the function file_put_contents() might be what you are looking for

Comment: That's it! I glossed over this function because I'd misunderstood its purpose thinking it can only store strings! Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help. Accepting the answer would be nice. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following: concatenate the header as follows:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'."$filename".'"');
```

And save the file via:

```
function file_put_contents()
```